# Rails create records with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, nested-attributes

My RSpec test to create records is failing.

In my Receipt class...

```
class Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :po_receipts, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
  has_many :jobquote_orders, through: :po_receipts
  validates_presence_of :receipt
  validates_presence_of :receipt_date
  validates_uniqueness_of :receipt, scope: :receipt_date, message: 'That receipt already exists.'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :po_receipts
end
```

receipts_controller_spec.rb

```
receipt1 = Fabricate.attributes_for(:receipt)
receipt1[:po_receipts_attributes] = {1 => {qty: 25, jobquote_order_id: 1}, 2 => {qty: 30, jobquote_order_id: 2}}
post :create, receipt: receipt1
expect(PoReceipt.count).to eq(2)
```

receipts_controller.rb

```
def new
  @receipt = Receipt.new
end

def create
  @receipt = Receipt.new(receipt_params)
  if is_user_or_admin?
    if @receipt.save
      flash[:success] = "Receipt created."
      redirect_to receipts_path
    else
      flash[:warning] = "Invalid data."
      render :new
    end
  else
    flash[:danger] = "You are not authorized to do that."
    redirect_to receipts_path
  end
end

private

def receipt_params
  params.require(:receipt).permit(:receipt, :receipt_date, po_receipts_attributes: [:qty, :jobquote_order_id])
end
```

I have also tried this for the strong parameters...

```
def receipt_params
  params.require(:receipt).permit(:receipt, :receipt_date, po_receipts_attributes: [])
end
```

I also have tried this for the strong parameters...

```
def receipt_params
  params.require(:receipt).permit(:receipt, :receipt_date).tap do |t|
    t[:po_receipts_attributes] = params[:receipt][:po_receipts_attributes]
  end
end
```

Here are the params being passed from the spec (and the view also)...

```
pry(#<ReceiptsController>)> params
  => {"receipt"=>
     {"receipt"=>"3cufkz",
      "receipt_date"=>"01/09/2014",
    "po_receipts_attributes"=>
      {0=>{"qty"=>"25", "jobquote_order_id"=>"1"},
      1=>{"qty"=>"30", "jobquote_order_id"=>"2"}}},
    "controller"=>"receipts",
    "action"=>"create"}
```

It will save the receipt, but will not save the po_receipts through the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :po_receipts`

Comment: In the rails server window, when you create one with nested attributes... you will normally see a message that tells you it is not accepting certain attributes and it's throwing them away. Can you try the create in your browser and watch for any error messages that say this and check whether it accepts the attributes there or not?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TarynEast. It actually fails silently. I ended up producing the RSpec params off of what the view produced in a browser. This is part of the reason why it is confusing me.

Comment: The rspec fail silently... but try it in the browser window while watching the server-logs. and look at what parameters actually get passed as a hash - then copy/paste these into your question. Then... also copy any line that is immediately after this that talks about parameters being removed as not being permitted - this will 100% always appear in the logs if your params are failing the permit/require line.